# display text generated via custom get query string

Tags: customization, query

I'm trying to display some text on my page, generating it via get query string, e.g. calling this url:
`mysite.com/page/?letter=exampletext`

If I understand correctly in such cases it is needed to *"add them to the public query variables available to WP_Query"* (stated here https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_query_var/), so I followed directions adding the following code to my page template:

```
<?php 
function queries( $qvars ) {
    $qvars[] = 'letter';
    return $qvars;
    }
add_filter( 'query_vars', 'queries' );

$text = get_query_var( 'letter' );
echo "letter is: ".$text;
?>
```

unfortunately this is not working as expected, since it only diplays the exlicit part of the string ("letter is: ").

What am I missing?
Thanks everyone

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**You should not use the query var API for that,** use `$_GET` or `filter_input` instead. `get_query_var` is for accessing parameters on the main `WP_Query`, not for retrieving URL GET parameters. Using this API for URLs is misleading and can trigger lots of unexpected problems.

The query variable API is for rewrite rules and `WP_Query`, e.g. for handling custom permalinks and virtual pages, etc. It was never intended for retrieving raw URL parameters in templates like that.

`get_query_var` will retrieve the value of the requested parameter that was used in the main query. That value may differ from the URL, or it may return a value despite not being in the URL at all. It can also be modified and intercepted via filters such as `pre_get_posts` or `parse_request`.

Another example is that if I visit `/mypage?foo=bar` then run this code:

```php
query_post('s=test');
echo get_query_var( 'foo' );
```

It will **not** print `bar`, because the current main query does not contain a `foo` query variable.

---

As for why your example does not work, the problem is that by the time your page template has loaded, the query variables filter has already run! The main query has already ran, it's already fetched your page, and already decided on the template to load. Your filter has been added yes, but the filter ran a long time ago, your code is waiting to board a train that has already left!

Generally, actions and filters don't belong in templates and are almost always a sign that a mistake has been made or that the user doesn't understand that actions/hooks/filters aren't a domain language, and that events on a timeline is a more accurate mental model. `add_actionn( 'init', 'foobar' )'` is equivalent to _from now on, if the `init` event happens, call `foobar`.

*It's not what you did, it's when you did it*. Put your filters/actions in a plugin or `functions.php` instead

Comment: thanks, the page originally fetched required string via standard php echo $_GET['string'], which now stopped working globally on the site. Btw I've tried your suggestion to put everything in functions.php without any luck, mysite.com/mypage/?letter=exampletext  produces the following echos:

`echo "queryvar paged: ".get_query_var('paged') ---> "queryvar paged: 0"`
`echo "queryvar letter: ".get_query_var('letter') ---> "queryvar letter: "`
`echo "normal: ".$_GET['letter'] ---> "normal: "`

note: code is in the file wp-content/themes/mytheme/templates/page-mypage.php, if useful

Comment: FORGET IT, problem was related to the .htaccess which got corrupted don't know how, once fixed your solution worked perfectly. thanks for you help

Comment: note that if `$_GET` stopped working then `get_query_var` won't fix it as WordPress also gets those values from get parameters unless you have it in a pretty permalink, e.g. `/foo/bar/` which you don't. `get_query_var` also returns things that aren't in the URL

Comment: To stress it further, ***do not use `get_query_var` to read in URL parameters***. Think of it as shorthand for `get_wp_query_parameter` not `get_url_query_value`. `get_query_var` does not do what you think it does. I've updated my answer to try and dispel any misunderstandings